# Download pdf file from url

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

i am trying to download PDF file from url in swift using Alamofire it shows damaged file .I need to add some extra parameters for security purpose .

Here is my URL format.

https://xyz.xom/123/PDF_1477.pdf?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=asasasasakskasajsa%3D&se=2016-10-26T18%3A34%3A21Z&sp=r .

When i try to paste this url in browser it downloads PDF from url. But when i try to download pdf from url in Swift using Alamofire it store some random bytes data . But there is no PDF file . When i try to open pdf ,It shows file is damaged.

Here is my code for Alamofire  .

```
   let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .ApplicationSupportDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

    Alamofire.download(.GET, url!, destination: destination).progress({ (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) in
        print(totalBytesRead)

        // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
        // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
        }
    }).response(completionHandler: { (request, response, data, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed with error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Downloaded file successfully")
        }
    })
```

Please help me solve .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: The link is broken. [Proof](http://imgur.com/a/pN1hm)

Comment: if link is broken then why should it works on browser .?

Comment: The Link is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue is solved now . I have removed URL encoding for my PDF url and passed with out encoding to Almofire download request . Thanks for your time and comment .